# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers') in my nextjs app using app router

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, rest, next.js

I am creating a very simple Rest API in Next.js, where i am trying to log "Hello world" in my console in a post api

```
export const POST = (req: Request) => {
  console.log('hello world');
};
```

this is the error I am receiving in my terminal

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:265:61)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I have no clue how I am making an error, can anyone help me out?

I browsed through some stackoverflow solutions, like fixing the JSON format in NextResponse.json() where I was sending it like this

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const errorResponse = async (error: any) => {
  return NextResponse.json({
    success: false,
    data: null,
    name: error.name || 'Unknown Error',
    message: error.message || 'An unknown error occured',
  });
};
```

So I tried to log every step while working on this Rest API, and I found the error in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a `NextResponse` instance from your `POST` method. Right now you return `undefined` by default which does not have a headers property (or any other property):

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  return NextResponse.json("hello world")
}
```